# JavaScript statements executed concurrently

Tags: javascript, concurrency

Can we execute two different statements together? Suppose these are the two statements

```
x += 2*y;
y = 2*x+3*y;
```

Here we can see the statements are dependent. So can we execute them concurrently?

Comment: By "together", do you mean concurrently?

Comment: Yes, I mean concurrently @Roy

Comment: @socialCircus, @Roy Dictus: Now could you explain what do you mean by executing 2 dependent statements concurrently? By being dependent it is pointless to execute them concurrently.

Comment: @socialCircus - Threading in Javascript? http://endertech.blogspot.com/2010/01/investigating-javascript-concurrency.html

Comment: @Andras Zoltan, @Roy Dictus: It doesn't have to do with threads at all. Even if it was possible, what s/he wants to do will create an infinite execution, which will never end, because one will never know what the value of the other is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you could calculate the overall change to the two variables and go to that directly (provided you take a snapshot of the values so that there's no actual data dependencies between them; did you know that a number of microprocessors will do this automatically, though only where the code is free of data dependencies?). Using your example and inventing a little fake syntax:

```
somehowInParallelWithSnapshotOf(x,y) {
    x <== 1*x + 2*y;
    y <== 2*x + 7*y;
}
```

But you can't do this in Javascript as the language doesn't support direct parallelism. (That has its advantages, of course. For one thing, it massively simplifies the semantics of the code, so allowing implementations to pull of tricks like this behind the scenes if they can prove its correct.) It would also be pointless for something as trivial as this example; there's quite a lot of overhead involved (in general) in spinning up extra threads, and when it gets up to the point of being worthwhile, it's usually very difficult to simplify the expressions to the point where you can make them hazard-free.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, dependent statements -- i.e., those that access state that the other one modifies -- can be executed concurrently, but you would not get consistent results.

But JavaScript is not concurrent, i.e. all lines are executed in sequence, even when you are executing a callback. JavaScript runs in the browser on a single thread.

Comment: At least not in today's browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, Javascript does not provide parallel/concurrent execution. The statements are executed sequentially, one after another. So, when the two statements are switched, the result changes. You could devise a kind of "parallel" vector operations:

```
function F(x, y) {
    return [x + 2*y, 2*x + 3*y];
}
var x, y;
[x, y] = F(1, 2);
```

The tuple assignment `[x, y] = ...` works only in some modern browsers that support Javascript 1.7 (e.g. Firefox, but not IE8). Another possibility would be to simulate vectors by objects:

```
function G(x, y) {
    return {x: x + 2*y, y: 2*x + 3*y};  // here, the statements can be switched
}
var z = G(1, 2);
// use z.x, z.y ...
```